# Upload files to gs bucket in for loop

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pypdf

In the below code a pdf document is splitted and kept in my local drive and once the splitting process completes the upload process takes place. In the upload process all the splitted files will be recursively uploaded to gs bucket. How can I convert my below code to upload the splitted file directly to the gs bucket instead of storing in local and then uploading? I tried but could not succeed

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import os
import glob
import sys
from google.cloud import storage

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(r"ace.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open(r"/home/playground/doc_pages/document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)

def upload_local_directory_to_gcs(local_path, bucket, gcs_path):
        assert os.path.isdir(local_path)
        for local_file in glob.glob(local_path + '/**'):
            if not os.path.isfile(local_file):
                continue
            remote_path = os.path.join(gcs_path, local_file[1 + len(local_path) :])
            storage_client = storage.Client()
            buck = storage_client.bucket(bucket)
            blob = buck.blob(remote_path)
            blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)
            print("Uploaded " + local_file + " to gs bucket " + bucket)

upload_local_directory_to_gcs('/home/playground/doc_pages', 'doc_pages', '')
```

Comment: You can store the file as a temporal file in `/tmp` this will be faster than writing to the disk.

Comment: @Juancki but how to store that file to gs bucket as and when it is splitted?

Comment: Please, look at my answer, does it work for you?

Comment: Great that worked like charm! Thanks a bunch.. if i convert this script to docker container what will the temporary file be? /tmp ?

Comment: In docker you can define the temporal file system with `--tempfs` to match `/tmp` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52662602/6003934

Comment: @Juancki  In this line of code **inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(r"ace.pdf", "rb"))** I am reading the input file from local which i want to get rid of by downloading it from bucket. If i download it to temporal folder can i still use the same way like /tmp/input/ace.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216131/discussion-between-sagar-sn-and-juancki).

Comment: Sure!, that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the temporal file it would look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import os
import glob
import sys
from google.cloud import storage

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(r"ace.pdf", "rb"))
# create temporal folder
os.makedirs('/tmp/doc_pages')   
for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    # Write to temporal files
    with open(r"/tmp/doc_pages/document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)

def upload_local_directory_to_gcs(local_path, bucket, gcs_path):
        assert os.path.isdir(local_path)
        for local_file in glob.glob(local_path + '/**'):
            if not os.path.isfile(local_file):
                continue
            remote_path = os.path.join(gcs_path, local_file[1 + len(local_path) :])
            storage_client = storage.Client()
            buck = storage_client.bucket(bucket)
            blob = buck.blob(remote_path)
            blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)
            print("Uploaded " + local_file + " to gs bucket " + bucket)

upload_local_directory_to_gcs('/tmp/doc_pages', 'doc_pages', '') # Change source
```

Comment: To delete the temporal folder use `os.remove('/tmp/doc_pages') this would avoid collisions between sequential executions